# Peut-on utiliser "troquer" pour des choses que l'on possède déjà ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

En faisant de la relecture pour le texte d'un ami, j'ai tiqué sur la phrase :

> Ils avaient troqués leurs vêtements de civils contre *leurs* uniformes [...]

"*Leurs*" impliquant qu'ils possédaient déjà ces uniformes.

Selon moi, *troquer*, même utilisé de manière figurée, implique de laisser tomber quelque chose et d'en adopter un nouveau mais que l'on ne possède pas encore. Mon ami m'a répondu que selon lui, ça voulait simplement dire "*échanger, remplacer par*" sans plus de restrictions de sens, et qu'échanger entre deux tenues que l'on possède ne pose pas de problème.

Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/troquer) donne le sens "*Abandonner, laisser quelque chose pour autre chose.*" qui correspond à cet usage mais donne pas plus d'informations.

Comment: @None ça ne répond pas à ma question. La plupart des dictionnaires ne donnent pas de précision et ont une définition peu restrictive, mais l'immense majorité des exemples (notamment ceux du Robert en lien) troquent un objet possédé contre un autre non-possédé. C'est peut-être trop *opinion-based* mais ma question est grosso modo : "*Est-ce que cet usage vous choque aussi ?*"

Comment: Sur le fond, le sens ne me choque pas mais dans la forme, l'emploi du possessif répété dans les deux parties de l'alternative (troquer *son*... contre *son*...) me semble peu commun. Un article indéfini comme dans l'exemple de @None est sans doute plus élégant. Par déduction le possessif sera sous-entendu dans la deuxieme partie.

Comment: @guillaume31 Tu as raison, c'est sans doute plus le double possessif plutôt que possessif puis indéfini qui me gêne, indépendamment de la notion de possession.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La phrase sur laquelle tu as un doute ne me choque pas du tout. L'emploi correspond bien a un usage répertorié, voir l'exemple donné dans le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* :

> 1- Donner en troc ➙ échanger.    (...)
> 2- (Sans idée de transaction commerciale). Changer ; faire succéder à.  ➙ échanger, remplacer. *Elle avait troqué son sarrau noir, sa courte robe de petite fille contre une jupe longue, contre un corsage de satinette rose à plis plats*. (Colette, *La Maison de Claudine*)

Si on se reporte au contexte d'où cette phrase est extraite, il est clair que les vêtements, ceux d'avant qu'elle se change et ceux d'après qu'elle se soit changée, sont déjà en sa possession, il n'est pas précisé si elle en est la « propriétaire » mais tous les vêtements proviennent de « son » atelier de couture à elle.

Autre phrase écrite cette fois par Hervé Bazin (*Lève-toi et marche*) :

> Voici Milandre, qui a pour une fois troqué son blouson maculé de peinture contre un de ces costumes verts de confection dont le carreau du Temple inonde les banlieues.

Et on peut même employer le verbe quand il s'agit de changer, une attitude contre une autre :

> Pour lui elle avait troqué son désir de peindre contre cette coquetterie. ... Puis rencontrant, aimant Courbet, elle avait troqué cette coquetterie enfantine de Narcisse contre le plaisir inconnu et capiteux... (Joëlle Tiano-Moussafir, *Le Dernier Courbet*)